check failed on EscapableHandleScope::Escape with v8 12.x.x version
I modified and tested the below Hello World code(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/v8/v8/12.3.219/samples/hello-world.cc) for the V8 engine(https://github.com/v8/v8) and found that it works well with v8 11.x.x version. However, it crashed or aborted with v8 12.3.x version in GetObjectTemplate.
Does anyone have any idea about that issue? or any mistake I made? Thanks!
void Test(v8::Local<v8::Name> name,
             const v8::PropertyCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& info) {
}

v8::Local<v8::ObjectTemplate> GetObjectTemplate(v8::Isolate* isolate)
{
  v8::EscapableHandleScope handle_scope(isolate);
  v8::Local<v8::ObjectTemplate> result = v8::ObjectTemplate::New(isolate);
  result->SetInternalFieldCount(1);
  result->SetHandler(v8::NamedPropertyHandlerConfiguration(Test));
  return handle_scope.Escape(result);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  // Initialize V8.
  v8::V8::InitializeICUDefaultLocation(argv[0]);
  v8::V8::InitializeExternalStartupData(argv[0]);
  std::unique_ptr<v8::Platform> platform = v8::platform::NewDefaultPlatform();
  v8::V8::InitializePlatform(platform.get());
  v8::V8::Initialize();

  // Create a new Isolate and make it the current one.
  v8::Isolate::CreateParams create_params;
  create_params.array_buffer_allocator =
      v8::ArrayBuffer::Allocator::NewDefaultAllocator();
  v8::Isolate* isolate = v8::Isolate::New(create_params);
  {
    v8::Isolate::Scope isolate_scope(isolate);

     // Create a stack-allocated handle scope.
    v8::HandleScope handle_scope(isolate);

    v8::Local<v8::ObjectTemplate> global = GetObjectTemplate(isolate);

    // Create a new context.
    v8::Local<v8::Context> context = v8::Context::New(isolate);

    // Enter the context for compiling and running the hello world script.
    v8::Context::Scope context_scope(context);

    {
      // Create a string containing the JavaScript source code.
      v8::Local<v8::String> source =
          v8::String::NewFromUtf8Literal(isolate, "'Hello' + ', World!'");

      // Compile the source code.
      v8::Local<v8::Script> script =
          v8::Script::Compile(context, source).ToLocalChecked();

      // Run the script to get the result.
      v8::Local<v8::Value> result = script->Run(context).ToLocalChecked();

      // Convert the result to an UTF8 string and print it.
      v8::String::Utf8Value utf8(isolate, result);
      printf("%s\n", *utf8);
    }
  }

  // Dispose the isolate and tear down V8.
  isolate->Dispose();
  v8::V8::Dispose();
  v8::V8::DisposePlatform();
  delete create_params.array_buffer_allocator;
  return 0;
}

The args are:
enable_iterator_debugging=false 
v8_monolithic=true 
v8_enable_i18n_support=false 
is_debug=true 
v8_use_external_startup_data=false 
use_custom_libcxx=false 
is_component_build=false 
treat_warnings_as_errors=false 
v8_symbol_level=0

Even without any change for Hello World, I still get the below crash when exiting with v8 12.3.x.
Thread 0 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   hello-world                            0x10d6b45de v8::internal::Isolate::EntryStackItem* std::__1::__cxx_atomic_load<v8::internal::Isolate::EntryStackItem*>(std::__1::__cxx_atomic_base_impl<v8::internal::Isolate::EntryStackItem*> const*, std::__1::memory_order) + 94
1   hello-world                            0x10d67984b std::__1::__atomic_base<v8::internal::Isolate::EntryStackItem*, false>::load(std::__1::memory_order) const + 27
2   hello-world                            0x10d67fcb1 v8::internal::Isolate::Exit() + 65
3   hello-world                            0x10d09986b v8::Isolate::Exit() + 43
4   hello-world                            0x10cf85798 v8::Isolate::Scope::~Scope() + 24
5   hello-world                            0x10cf85335 v8::Isolate::Scope::~Scope() + 21
6   hello-world                            0x10cf85046 test() + 1478
7   hello-world                            0x10cf85420 main + 160
8   dyld                                0x7ff80b26341f start + 1903

